# why $RM \neq 0$

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Definition:  we said that $M$ is simple if $RM \neq 0$
and $M$ has no proper submodule.

i couldnt understand why it must be  $RM \neq 0$

could you please explain why ? Thank you for your helping.

Comment: Surely not $\Bbb R$ as in the real numbers. For $M$ there is no reason either for using a far-fetched font.

Answer (score 2):

This is the definition for "simple module" adopted for rings which do not necessarily have identity and/or modules which are not assumed to be unital. For rings with identity, we usually assume that $1\cdot m=m$ for all $m\in M$, and in that case, the definition can omit the part about $RM\neq \{0\}$.

I'm not sure where you encountered the definition, but I remember I learned it in Jacobson's *[Structure of rings](http://books.google.com/books?id=KlMDjaJxZAkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Structure+of+rings%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1mw5U_29IeHNsQT404CgBw&ved=0CEYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=modular%20ideal&f=false)* (page 5). It turns out that you can find an isomorphism $M\cong R/L$ for a maximal left ideal (which is also a modular left ideal) of $R$ iff $RM\neq 0$ and $M$ has no nontrivial submodules.

($\Leftarrow$) If $RM\neq\{0\}$, pick $r, m$ such that $rm\neq 0$. Then the map $r\mapsto rm$ from $R\to M$ is onto $M$, and the first isomorphism theorem retrieves $L$ such that $R/L\cong M$.

($\Rightarrow$) Let $L$ be a maximal left ideal which is also [modular](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Modular_ideal). This means that there exists $e\in R$ such that for all $x\in R$, $x\equiv ex$ in $R/L$. So if you take any nonzero $y\in R/L$ and conjure up the $e\in R$ that does this, $y\equiv ey\neq 0$ in $R/L$, proving that $R(R/L)\neq \{0\}$.

Other modules which only have the two trivial submodules, but unfortunately also have $RM=\{0\}$ do not have this nice property, so they are not as important. One example of such a module is the $2\Bbb Z$ module $2\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Why isn't 4Z a maximal left ideal of 2Z? It is a subgroup, and closed under the operations, and since the index is prime, it is definitely maximal.  Is "modular" added to the definition of maximal or ideal?

Comment: @JackSchmidt Hmm, I'll have to check. The quotient is only two elements, so it'd have to be maximal. Maybe I'm misremembering that  maximals have to be modular... but I thought it was true that all proper ideals embed in a maximal modular ideal! So I'll double check as we speak. If you want to look yourself, the Structure of Rings googlebook link will help you.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Oh, now I know what I misremembered. *Modular* ideals can be embedded in maximal modular ideals. I'll have to modify the wording. And the adjectives "maximal" and "modular" aren't supposed to be intermingled. My mistake was in saying that maximal ideals are always modular. The example I gave turns out to be a maximal nonmodular ideal.